# Trigonometric inequality involving $\sec(a-b)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am trying to prove the following inequality:
If $a,b \in\left(0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$, prove that $\;\dfrac{\sin^3a}{\cos a}+\dfrac{\sin^3b}{\cos b} \geqslant\sec(a-b)$.

I have rewritten the expression using the fact that $\;\sec(a-b)=\dfrac{1}{\cos(a-b)}=\dfrac{1}{\cos a\,\cos b+\sin a\,\sin b}\;$ so that it remains to prove:

$$\left(\frac{\sin^3a}{\cos a}+\frac{\sin^3b}{\cos b} \right)\big(\cos a\,\cos b+\sin a\,\sin b\big) \geqslant 1$$

I was given the hint of using Cauchy-Schwarz but I don't have a clue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please use `\sin`, `\cos` to write trigonometric ratio names, and maybe use `()` to enclose the argument. Also is it "sen" or "sin"?

Comment: @Krosin I have submitted a pending edit for improved formatting. Also, sen could be sec.

Comment: Oh, it's true. My fault. I have edited and now it is correct.

Comment: Consider $a=b \to 0^+$, it will be clear the inequality is false. Where did you get this and have you copied the LHS correctly?

Comment: You are right @Macavity, it was a task from my professor. I've asked him and he says that he made a mistake: the inequality that must be proven is in the other sense, that is to say, change the LHS and RHS.

Comment: The thing is that I have been trying again to establish the inequality trying to choose appropiate vectors to apply Cauchy-Schwarz but I haven't been able to. Any idea is welcome. Thanks.